# How to copy files from one folder to another folder in azure storage in the same container in python?

Tags: azure

Azure-storage-blob only contains the copy_from_url which copies from a standalone hosted file, not a file in azure storage container.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples Refer to this

Answer (score 0):

```
bc = BlobClient.from_connection_string(c["LANDING_CONNECTION_STRING"],c["LANDING_CONTAINER_NAME"],c["blobDirectory"]+"/"+blobname)
client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(c["LANDING_CONNECTION_STRING"])
new_blob = client.get_blob_client(c["LANDING_CONTAINER_NAME"],c["ArchivalDirectory"]+"/"+blobname)
new_blob.start_copy_from_url(bc.url)
```